# SQl string split (parse) on space where some field values have no space

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've been trying to split a string value in my query to return the first part of a two part postcode in a new column.  Some values have only the first part, and some have both.  After a bit of searching I found this code:

```
SELECT
  TblPLSSU.PLSSUPostcode  
  ,SUBSTRING(TblPLSSU.PLSSUPostcode, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', TblPLSSU.PLSSUPostcode)) AS PCode
FROM 
TblPostcodes
```

This happily splits the values that have two parts to the postcode but it seems to be ignoring the single part post codes.

For example, values for TblPLSSU.PLSSUPostcode  might be:

```
EH1 1AB 
EH2
```

I want to return the values

```
EH1 
EH2
```

But with the code above I am only getting EH1

Thanks
Eils

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `case` to pick up post codes as-is when they don't have a space separated value.

```
SELECT
PLSSUPostcode  
,case when CHARINDEX(' ', PLSSUPostcode) > 0 
 then SUBSTRING(PLSSUPostcode, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', PLSSUPostcode))
else PLSSUPostcode end AS PCode
FROM 
TblPostcodes
```

Comment: Thanks - is there a missing ( on this code?  Trying to work out where it should go....

Comment: i can't see one. did you try the answer as it is?

Answer (score 1):

Use `case` as well:

```
SELECT TblPLSSU.PLSSUPostcode, 
       (CASE WHEN TblPLSSU.PLSSUPostcode LIKE '% %'
             THEN SUBSTRING(TblPLSSU.PLSSUPostcode, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', TblPLSSU.PLSSUPostcode)) 
        END) AS PCode
FROM . . .
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I'm still just getting a value for postcodes with two parts with this code.

Answer (score 1):

A little trick with `STUFF` function. This works because of `CHARINDEX` returns index of the first occurrence. So you are just adding space to strings and replacing all symbols from first occurrence till the end with empty string:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(v VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES('EH1 1AB'), ('EH2')

SELECT STUFF(v + ' ', CHARINDEX(' ', v + ' '), LEN(v), '')
FROM @t
```

Another version:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(v + ' ', 1, CHARINDEX(' ', v + ' ') - 1)
FROM @t
```

Output:

```
EH1
EH2
```

Comment: thanks.  Answer above works but I will have a closer look at stuff function as it looks like it might be useful in future.